# Key-Value storage with realtime multimaster replication

Tags: nosql, distributed, key-value, distributed-caching, distributed-database

Are there any opensource distributed key-value storage which satisfy following conditions.

- Almost real-time multimaster replication. (tie-breaker will be based on timestamp and not anything more complicated)
- Each node should be able to work with it's local data if disconnected from the rest of the nodes(Consistent hashing based approaches will not be feasible).
- Max number of nodes expected ~10.

Evaluated the following.

- memcachedb
- couchdb
- cassandra

and found that the above ones does not satisfy all the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra possibly meets these requirements **IF** you set a low consistency level for queries, so that each node replies immediately without checking with any other nodes **AND** set the replication factor to equal the number of nodes (so all data is replicated to all nodes).

Why do you have these specific (unusual) requirements, though? i.e. why do you effectively want 10x replication with full partition-tolerance?

Comment: It is not for a web/cloud product where we can control the boxes once deployed. It is an enterprise product with multiple boxes forming a single cluster and geographically separated (I Know its a weired requirement) :(. How much realtime is cassandra ?